# Only allow `EncryptedMessage` for ServiceStack host

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I am building a [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net) service that runs on several dozen embedded devices.  I'd like to ensure that all communication to the device occurs over an encrypted channel.  I've researched various SSL/TLS options, but managing several dozen different certs, or publishing a single cert to dozens of device, seems like a lot of overhead.

I've been looking at the [Encrypted Messaging](http://docs.servicestack.net/encrypted-messaging) feature, but it appears that this only offers a transparent overlay, which would allow either a plain DTO or an encrypted DTO to be sent.

Is there any way to restrict my endpoints to ONLY accept `EncryptedMessage` DTOs, while preserving the ability to process them internally?  Some sort of filter that can tell the original DTO came from an `EncryptedMessage` originally maybe?

I've considered the [Service Gateway](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway), but it seems like I'd have to have two separate AppHosts - one to receive the encrypted data and one (internal only) to process & respond.  Seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just marked Encrypted Messaging Requests as Secure in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/12b4ba42e4cdea7586d21571b0fc296e917efcf2) which will allow you to use the [Restricting Services Attribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/restricting-services) to ensure only secure Requests are made with:

```
[Restrict(RequestAttributes.Secure)]
public class SecureOnlyServices { }

[Restrict(RequestAttributes.InSecure | RequestAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess,
          RequestAttributes.Secure   | RequestAttributes.External)]
public class InternalHttpAndExternalSecure { }
```

This change is available from v4.5.13 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Earlier versions of ServiceStack can check the `IRequest.Items` dictionary to determine if it's an Encrypted Messaging Request with:

```
var isEncryptedMessagingRequest = base.Request.Items.ContainsKey("_encryptCryptKey");
if (!isEncryptedMessagingRequest)
    throw new HttpError.Forbidden("Only secure requests allowed");
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz.  It seemed like the `RestrictAttribute` was the way to go, but I didn't want to roll my own!